# What are the extra features of Cave Story on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, cave-story, wiiware

I recently was told that Cave Story was ported to the Wii. It was an excellent game on the PC, the perfect match of excellent gameplay and story. The Wii version isn't just a straight port, is it? Are there extra features available that will provide a completely new experience to the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than everything being hi-def-ier (Video and music wise), the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_Story#Versions_and_ports) seems to list a few extra game modes (and naturally you can check out the references for that info).

Comment: Any chance for some explanations of those new modes here on the Gaming site? Or have you not gotten to try out those modes yourself yet?

Comment: Seeing how I don't own a Wii, then I can't say I've had the pleasure of playing the relevant version of Cave Story.

Comment: Hrm. Very well. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone might be able to provide this data.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that there is a unused level that can be unlocked after beating the game called Wind Fortress. Also, a boss rush mode and Curly story where Curly is the protagonist instead of Quote.